# Smart Contract Function

Tags: blockchain, binance-smart-chain

I'm trying to implement an ICO contract on the Binance network.
The `buyTokens()` function is not working.

when I run the function in Remix using the value WEI, it works.

When I run the function using value ether, it returns an error:

> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The
> transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
> Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution
> reverted" }

I don't know why it doesn't work with ether

code `buyTokens()`:

```
function buyTokens() public payable whenSaleIsActive {
    uint256 weiAmount = msg.value; // Calculate tokens to sell
    uint256 tokens = weiAmount.mul(RATE);

    emit BoughtTokens(msg.sender, tokens); // log event onto the blockchain
    raisedAmount = raisedAmount.add(msg.value); // Increment raised amount
    token.transfer(msg.sender, tokens); // Send tokens to buyer

    owner.transfer(msg.value);// Send money to owner
}
```

Contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT   
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

/**
* @title SafeMath
* @dev Math operations with safety checks that throw on error
*/
library SafeMath {
    /**
    * mul 
    * @dev Safe math multiply function
    */
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a * b;
        assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
        return c;
    }
    /**
    * add
    * @dev Safe math addition function
    */
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a);
        return c;
    }
}

/**
* @title Ownable
* @dev Ownable has an owner address to simplify "user permissions".
*/
contract Ownable {
    address public owner;

    /**
    * Ownable
    * @dev Ownable constructor sets the `owner` of the contract to sender
    */
    function Ownable() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    /**
    * ownerOnly
    * @dev Throws an error if called by any account other than the owner.
    */
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    /**
    * transferOwnership
    * @dev Allows the current owner to transfer control of the contract to a newOwner.
    * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to.
    */
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0));
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

/**
* @title Token
* @dev API interface for interacting with the WILD Token contract 
*/
interface Token {
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) external returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address _owner) external constant returns (uint256 balance);
}

/**
* @title Contract ICO
* @dev ContractICO contract is Ownable
**/
contract ContractICO is Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    Token token;

    uint256 public constant RATE = 1500000; // Number of tokens per Ether
    uint256 public constant CAP = 9350; // Cap in Ether
    uint256 public constant START = 1639047009;// 12/09/2021
    uint256 public constant DAYS = 45; // 45 Day

    uint256 public constant initialTokens = 6000000; // Initial number of tokens available
    bool public initialized = false;
    uint256 public raisedAmount = 0;

    /**
    * BoughtTokens
    * @dev Log tokens bought onto the blockchain
    */
    event BoughtTokens(address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /**
    * whenSaleIsActive
    * @dev ensures that the contract is still active
    **/
    modifier whenSaleIsActive() {
        // Check if sale is active
        assert(isActive());
        _;
    }

    /**
    * ContractICO 
    * @dev ContractICO constructor
    **/
    function ContractICO(address _tokenAddr) public {
        require(_tokenAddr != 0);
        token = Token(_tokenAddr);
    }

    /**
    * initialize
    * @dev Initialize the contract
    **/
    function initialize() public onlyOwner {
        require(initialized == false); // Can only be initialized once
        require(tokensAvailable() == initialTokens); // Must have enough tokens allocated
        initialized = true;
    }

    /**
    * isActive
    * @dev Determins if the contract is still active
    **/
    function isActive() public view returns (bool) {
        return (
            initialized == true &&
            now >= START && // Must be after the START date
            now <= START.add(DAYS * 1 days) && // Must be before the end date
            goalReached() == false // Goal must not already be reached
        );
    }

    /**
    * goalReached
    * @dev Function to determin is goal has been reached
    **/
    function goalReached() public view returns (bool) {
        return (raisedAmount >= CAP * 1 ether);
    }

    /**
    * @dev Fallback function if ether is sent to address insted of buyTokens function
    **/
    function () public payable {
        buyTokens();
    }

    /**
    * buyTokens
    * @dev function that sells available tokens
    **/
    function buyTokens() public payable whenSaleIsActive {
        uint256 weiAmount = msg.value; // Calculate tokens to sell
        uint256 tokens = weiAmount.mul(RATE);

        emit BoughtTokens(msg.sender, tokens); // log event onto the blockchain
        raisedAmount = raisedAmount.add(msg.value); // Increment raised amount
        token.transfer(msg.sender, tokens); // Send tokens to buyer

        owner.transfer(msg.value);// Send money to owner
    }

    /**
    * tokensAvailable
    * @dev returns the number of tokens allocated to this contract
    **/
    function tokensAvailable() public constant returns (uint256) {
        return token.balanceOf(this);
    }

    /**
    * destroy
    * @notice Terminate contract and refund to owner
    **/
    function destroy() onlyOwner public {
        // Transfer tokens back to owner
        uint256 balance = token.balanceOf(this);
        assert(balance > 0);
        token.transfer(owner, balance);
        // There should be no ether in the contract but just in case
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }
}
```

Comment: "When I run the function using value ether, it returns an error" - What does it mean "using value ether"?

Comment: I already found my error, the msg.value comes from the default 18 decimals.
and my token is 9 decimal.

my problem now is how do i convert this?
doing the division (msg.value / 1 * 10 ** 18), when I send value below 1 ether it gives an error in the contract. example: sending 0.1 ether to the ICO contract, it returns an error, but if I send 1 ether it runs correctly